# Injecting Repository in Controller - Class does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've created `App/Repositories/HelloRepository`, but get `Class App\Http\Controllers\HelloRepository does not exist`

What am I missing to be able to inject my new repository into my controller

Repository:

```
namespace App\Repositories;

class HelloRepository
{
    public function sayHello()
    {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories;

    public function index(HelloRepository $repo)
    {
        dd($repo->sayHello());
    }
```

Comment: If you're using repositories, you really shouldn't inject a concretion (class), but an abstraction (interface) otherwise you're missing a main benefit that repositories provide.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you point to an example?

Comment: Research dependency inversion principle (the D in SOLID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the use "use App\Repositories;", the name of the Repository is missed.

```
use App\Repositories\HelloRepository
```

Comment: thanks, now I get the `Class App\Repositories\HelloRepository does not exist` error. See update above. HelloRepository is not a directory but a .php file. Shoul've specified that in the begining. See **Edit** above.

Comment: Do you have the tag <?php in the start of your file?

Answer (score 1):

put this at the at the top, i.e after you set `namespace`

```
use App\Repositories\HelloRepository
```

and remove

```
use App\Repositories;
```

Comment: thanks, now I get the `Class App\Repositories\HelloRepository does not exist` error. See update above. HelloRepository is not a directory but a .php file. Shoul've specified that in the begining. See **Edit** above.